# Discord js members loop returns only single user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to get all the users in my servers on ready of my discord bot so that I can add them to a database.

I have the discord privileged gateway intents all turned on. But I am only getting the id of a single user with the following code:

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    client.guilds.cache.values().next().value.members.list().then((members) => {
        members.each(member => {
            console.log(member.id)
        });
    })
})
```

I am sure I have included all the intent that would be necessary while creating my client:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_BANS", "GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS",
    "GUILD_INTEGRATIONS", "GUILD_WEBHOOKS", "GUILD_INVITES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES", "GUILD_PRESENCES", "GUILD_MESSAGES",
    "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS", "GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING"]} )
```

I dont know why it is giving id of only 1 member (owner) while the test server has 3 members including the bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
client.guilds.cache.get(guild_id).members.cache.map(member => member.id)
```

Comment: yes this works but why does my code return only 1 user. I am fairly new to JS sorry.

Comment: @AllLuckBased to be honest, I have no idea why it's not working, but code I provided is more optimized